# How to draw a parallel arrow to a line

Tags: plotting

How can I draw an arrow starting from a point and ending up at a certain point on a curve being parallel to $y=-x$ line.

Comment: Look up `Arrow`, `Graphics3D`, and `Show` in the documentation.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I had a quick look. My problem is that I don't know how can I draw an arrow parallel to a line.

Comment: @Immanuel Your problem statement seems to be unclear.  If you know the end point and the slope, then you have specified the line the arrow lies on, and you can just pick another point on that line.  What is making the problem harder than this?

Comment: @Alan I want to connect a point from a curve to a point from another one on a parallel line to $y=-x$ with an arrow.

Comment: @Alan I managed to draw a parallel arrow. I can't now say where the arrow should stop (meaning the end point on the second curve).

Comment: edit the question to show some example. As it its not clear what you are trying to do.  (How is your "curve" represented ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f1 = Sin   (* arbitrary first function *)
f2 = #^2/36 &  (* arbitrary second function *)
{x0, y0} = {1, f1[x0]}  (* arbitrary point on first fn *)
f3 = Function[x, y0 - (x - x0)] (* line though point *)
xsol = x /. Last@Solve[f2[x] == f3[x], x] (* line crosses 2nd fn *)
Plot[{f1[x], f2[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi},
 Epilog -> Arrow[{{x0, y0}, {xsol, f3[xsol]}}]]
```